# Flutter Stream.periodic - anyway to not send event?

Tags: flutter

With the "Stream.periodic" function,  is there anyway to inject logic into the computation function so that an event is not dispatched to the stream?

For instance, I am creating a stream event every minute, but there is logic in the computation function that means that not every event needs to be sent.

In this example shown below, I am building a RiverPod stream provider that will emit an event when a new calendar day is detected.  Is this the best way of coding such a solution?

```
final newDayProvider= StreamProvider<DateTime?>((ref)  async* {

  const String aPropName = 'dayCheckerTimestamp';

  await for (final  aDate in Stream<DateTime?>.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), (_) {
    var aDayHasChanged = false;
    final aStr = ref.read(sharedPrefsProvider).getString(aPropName);
    final aNow = DateTime.now();
    if (aStr != null) {
      DateTime aPrev = DateTime.parse(aStr);
      aDayHasChanged = (aNow.day != aPrev.day) || (aNow.month != aPrev.month) || (aNow.year != aPrev.year);
    }
    ref.read(sharedPrefsProvider).setString(aPropName,aNow.toIso8601String());
    if (aDayHasChanged) {
      return aNow;
    }
    return null;
  })
  ) {
    if (aDate != null) {
      yield aDate;
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: If `aDate` is equal to the previous yielded value the widgets will not get updated, [StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html) expects the stream values to be inmutables by default.